# print the content of a WebView

Tags: android, printing, webview, bitmap

I have a function that gets a Bitmap object and prints it with the device's built-in printer.
The bitmap I send it, is a bitmap I captured in the WebView. 
But I have a problem :
It captures only part of the webview in height, that is only the part that's visible before having to scroll down inside the webview to see the remaining content.

```
....

webViewToPrint = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView2);

webViewToPrint.setInitialScale( 100 );
webViewToPrint.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webViewToPrint.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webViewToPrint.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewToPrint.loadDataWithBaseURL("", dataToPrintFinal, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
webViewToPrint.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               super.onPageFinished(view, url);

               view.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {          
                       Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( webViewToPrint.getWidth() , webViewToPrint.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                       Canvas canvas = new Canvas( b );
                       webViewToPrint.draw(canvas);

                       printPicture(b);
                   }},500);
       }});
 ....
```

It also prints it too small and cornered (instead of aligning it in the center).